# Alternative Methods to Refresh BlazorWebView Content in a MAUI Blazor App

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am developing a cross-platform application using MAUI Blazor. I'm utilizing the BlazorWebView component to display web content. My goal is to programmatically refresh the content inside this component when certain conditions are met (for example, 30 seconds after a specific event occurs).

The issue I'm facing is that it seems BlazorWebView does not directly provide a Reload method or a Source property that I can use for refreshing its content. Excluding the approach of using JSinterop, I'm interested in finding out if there are any alternative methods to achieve this.

Has anyone dealt with a similar challenge or can recommend a way to refresh the content of a BlazorWebView component under specific conditions? Any shared experience or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The BlazorWebView is capable of utilizing the same DI container as the rest of your app. you should make a class that has an event that you would raise when the mentioned conditions are met, and then register that class as a singleton in your DI, and then resolve it in your Blazor page that is running in your BlazorWebView, and listen for that event, then just refresh the data from there. I'm not sure if you are refering to a page refresh, or just reloading some of the components, but either way you should be able to do it from the Blazor components when the event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavigationManager` in `OnAfterRender()` method to automatically refresh the content of the BlazorWebView component at a specified interval(below exmple is 3 seconds). Below the `NavigateTo(“url”, forceLoad: true)` method, is used to force load the browser based on the URI.

```
@inject NavigationManager uriHelper;
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
            {
                uriHelper.NavigateTo(uriHelper.Uri, forceLoad: true);
            }), null, 3000, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```